# Multi threading and getting An Error Calling Function

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, file-io

writing a code to multi thread using Microsoft Kinect VS 2013.

```
char fnameC[sizeof "C:\\Users\\Adam\\Desktop\\Skeleton_RGBDepth_DataAcquisition2013\\Skeleton_RGBDepth_DataAcquisition2013\\Color_Image\\Color_01_c1_00_00_000.png"];
char fnameD[sizeof "C:\\Users\\Adam\\Desktop\\Skeleton_RGBDepth_DataAcquisition2013\\Skeleton_RGBDepth_DataAcquisition2013\\Depth_Image\\Depth_01_c1_00_00_000.png"];

int main() {
 set up stuff....

 while(1) {
    setup of the color image frame and depth image frame...

    std::thread im01(cv::imwrite, std::ref(fnameC), std::ref(colorImage));
    std::thread im02(cv::imwrite, std::ref(fnameD), std::ref(depthImage));

    im01.join();
    im02.join();


}
}
```

I get an error:

> Error 1   error C2090: function returns array c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xrefwrap 432 1   Skeleton_RGBDepth_DataAcquisition2013

Not really sure whats going on...Need help thanks; would love a!

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a defect in VS, since a [reference wrapper](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) should only return references on `.get()` or implicit casting via `operator T&` and therefore shouldn't trigger this error. Note that your problem wasn't reproduceable in g++ 4.8.2. However, if you drop the reference wrapper, you should be fine.

Either way, [`cv::imwrite`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#bool%20imwrite%28const%20string&%20filename,%20InputArray%20img,%20const%20vector%3Cint%3E&%20params%29) expects a `const std::string&`, not a `char (&)[136]`. It's way better to work with `std::string`s anyway, so this would be a good time to look into them.

Answer (score 1):

`C2090` is [Compiler Error C2090](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs34td6x.aspx):

```
A function cannot return an array. Return a pointer to an array instead.
The following sample generates C2090:
// C2090.cpp
int func1(void)[] {}   // C2090
```

You hit this in `xrefwrap:432`. This is caused by `std::ref(fnameC)` and the definition of `char fnameC[...]`. The resulted `std::reference_wrapper<char[]>.Get()` is supposed to return `char[]`, hence the error.

PS. Use MAX_PATH for path buffers. Use `std::string` for strings.